# Monitoring insert into statements from remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have written a procedure that runs a bunch of `select into` statements from remote linked servers.
These servers have been known to simply hang and not respond for some reason, however my insert into statement will continue endlessly.

Is there a way in SQL server I can monitor the destination table to see if data is going in? I am not using transactions. When I try to select from the destination table, it must be locked because it is basically sitting there waiting. I changed my isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED` and can get a select on the table, but the count isn't moving, so I am assuming the data goes in batches?

I am running a tcpdump on the remote server and can see the packets flowing through, just hoping there is an easier way to see it through MSSQL somewhere.

Any advise appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

SQL profiler is your friend.

open SSMS and goto Tools -> SQL Server Profiler.  Then setup the criteria, and there are ALOT OF THEM.  I always start big and whittle it down.

Some advise, make sure you know what the account is that is being used to execute the statement.  As well, only run it for no more than 10-20 mins, cause these Profiler files can eat up 100GB/session in minutes.  While looking for the statement, only start it before you execute the statement and stop it after you get the result and then find your statement information and then refine the Profiler for what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite help. The profiler shows me that the statement has started, however it doesn't show me if the statement is actually doing anything or whether it has frozen somewhere along the line.

Comment: did you include the StatementStart and StatementEnd.  There are a alot of options.  Run the query against the database itself. then Run it remotely and see what the execution time difference is.  Forgot to mention, check the Result Set return, for rows affected to see if the data went in.

Comment: Problem with LinkedServers, is that you loose some control, on verifiability.  SQL sends the command, but because its usually not part of the native environment, it cant verify that the execution was a success or failure, in most of the situations i have run against.  The only way to verify the information went in, was to run a select statement against the destination and see if it went in.  Linked servers should really be used only as a Data Source, not a RDBMS connection.  I would advise using a SSIS package to act outside the environments of both.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the Profiler, but that is not my problem. The profiler will only show the start and end of statements. I have statements that simply freeze at the linked server end, with SQL waiting for data that it will never come, so the profiler isn't showing this. I want to see that the data is still inserting into the table, but I've tried difference transaction isolation levels and cannot see data being inserted so that is no help.

Comment: Do you control the LinkedServer?  If not, then you are SOL.  I would suggest you use SSIS/BIDS to perform the execution you need.  LinkedServers are unreliable if you can not have control of both servers.  Say internal SQL Server 2008r2 Linked to Shared Hosting on GoDaddy MySQL instance.